# how to write javascript in asp.net in code behind using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

How can I write JavaScript code in asp.net in code behind using C#?

For example:
I have click button event when I click the button I want to invoke this java script code:

```
alert("You pressed Me!");
```

I want to know how to use java script from code behind.

Comment: I'd recommend looking into using the jQuery libraries instead of pure Javascript.

Comment: @David. The same principles apply to both. jQuery is just javascript, after all.

Comment: Indeed - but for someone starting out in javascript they will often find their development much easier if they use jQuery. Just spreading the word :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Actually, this is what you need:

```
string myScriptValue = "function callMe() {alert('You pressed Me!'); }";
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "myScriptName", myScriptValue, true);
```

Copy all of javascript into string and then register it into your aspx page in code-behind. Then in aspx page, you can call the javascript function whenever you want. You should write this code in Page_Load method in C# page.

Comment: Thanks, I also needed to prefix ScriptManager with System.Web.UI. I already had System.Web.Extensions referenced in my VS2013 project.

Answer (score 13):

Have a look at the ScriptManager class' [RegisterClientScriptBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerclientscriptblock.aspx) and [RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx) methods.

Answer (score 7):

One way to put some javascript onto the page into a specific location do this:

ASP.Net

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<asp:Literal id="litScript" runat="server" />
</script>
```

C#

```
litScript.Text = "alert("Hello!");"
```

Of course, you can put anything in there, and I'd recommend a javascript library.

Using the Scriptmanager is also an option.

Comment: I think this is an option when you have to do something really tricky, but I wouldn't use it in this case.

Comment: Thanks, this is the solution I was looking for. Using `<script runat="server">` directly doesn't work, the control variable is always null. Other HTML elements work fine. This does cause funny colours in the HTML source editor though...

Answer (score 7):

Not an answer, but a suggestion.
Mixing your js within your code-behind can come back to haunt you, I agree with Adrian Magdas.
Anytime you need to make a simple change/update to your javascript you'll have to re-build your project, which means re-deploying instead of simply pushing out a single .js file.

Answer (score 6):

Something like:

```
btnSomething.ClientClick = "alert('You pressed me!');";
```

You might also want to read up on the ScriptManager control and outputting blocks of script.

Answer (score 6):

The right answers usually is "You don't". It's better to define your code in a .js file and use jQuery to hook-up the desired events.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
 $('#myBtn').click(function() {
  alert('Handler for .click() called.');
});};
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to register a script that will be used in connection with an `UpdatePanel` (AJAX) use `ScriptManager` class as Sani Huttunen pointed.
Otherwise you should use the class [ClientScriptManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager%28VS.80%29.aspx) (methods [Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerclientscriptblock%28VS.80%29.aspx) or [Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript%28VS.80%29.aspx))

As other user pointed, normally registering a script on the code behind can and should be avoided. It's not a very nice practice and you should do it only in cases where you have no other option.

Answer (score 3):

```css
Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('You pressed Me!');</script>");
```