# Close FaceBox from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, facebox

I am having trouble closing jQuery Facebox from code behind. I am inserting a new record through FaceBox, on successful insertion the FaceBox needs to be closed. How can i achieve this?

Comment: Can you show us more code? Ideally the javascript that is used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

Aspx page:

//Add data fields and button from an user control

Aspx.cs page:

Page page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
        if (page != null)
        {
           ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, page.GetType(), "err_msg",       "close_facebox()", true);
        }

Js function:

function close_facebox() { 
            $('#addlink').css('display', 'none');
            $('#addlink').overlay().close();
  }

Answer (score 1):

Facebox exposes some events, one of them is `facebox.close`. So, you could do something like this:

```
function add_record() {
    // ... add the record here ...
    jQuery(document).trigger('close.facebox');
    //or: $(document).trigger('close.facebox');
}
```

That should close the facebox for you.

EDIT: To do this via code-behind, it looks like you'll need to write the actual javascript from your code-behind page. I'm not a .NET programmer, but this question looks like it might point you in the right direction: [how to write javascript in asp.net in code behind using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848359)

The key is that if you trigger the `close.facebox` event, Facebox will close.

Comment: I tried the above, but it's not working. What script is being called once user clicks on the default Facebox close button? Can I call the same script from .cs file?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I'm not a .net programmer so I wasn't sure what code-behind meant in your question. I just assumed you meant the regular javascript code on the page. My answer is a javascript function that would need to be called in javascript once the record is actually added.

Comment: <div id="addlink" class="facebox" style="background: #fff;">
            <div class="close close-btn">
                &nbsp;</div> // fields to add record with a button.      
        </div>   I can call a JS function from code behind. What should I have in the JS function in this scenario ?

Comment: The JS function should call: `$(document).trigger('close.facebox');`