# How to calculate width of unused space for page with fixed width?

Tags: html, css

I am new to css and need some advise. I have DIV with content of webpage with fixed width (1140 px) and green background which is centered in the middle.

```
{position: relative; width: 1140px; height: 2000px; top: 0px; z-index:1; margin: 0px auto }
```

What I want to achieve now are 2 divs on sides which contain just color of webpage fading into white. So border of screen is white and place where it meets central div is green. I know about linear-gradient property. Problem is that I dont know how wide these DIVs will be. Is there a way to make them relative to the central DIV so they fill whole remaining space to the side or I have to calculate it?

Does someone have a simple and elegant answer to this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: can you show us a example ? you can use `calc()` to calculate the width

Comment: Hello,lets say I have "div-mid" as a centered div which contains my webpage. Its width is 1140 px. Now I need to define "div-left" and "div-right", but I dont know how wide they are.

I tried calc(), specifically this command, but calc() doesnt recognize it --> width:calc((100% - 1140px) / 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to fill up exactly the remaining space. You can make simple calculations in your css using `calc` and there is a unit of measurement `vw` that can come in very handy for this.

**100 vw  = 100% of the viewport width**

so if you know your center div is always 1140 px, you can easily calculate the width of the side div's like this:

```
width: calc((100vw - 1140px)/2);
```

Browser support should be fairly good nowadays:

- [vh, vw, vmin, vmax](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)
- [calc](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc)

One sidenote, consider working with pseudo elements `:after` and `:before` in stead of adding extra divs just for styling, which is considered bad practice. You should bever add markup just for styling.

A small demonstration of how I would do it:
http://jsfiddle.net/669t4s3L/

Comment: thanks, this did the job. Part of the problem with calc() was that I had outdated IE. After upgrade calc() works fine

Comment: Remember that vh is calculated as if the scrollbar isn't there so once your content goes below the fold you will have a permanent horizontal scrollbar. Therefore just knock another 20px off the calculation to be safe e.g.  width: calc((100vw - 520px) / 2);. (Or use position fixed  for the pseudo elements and place  at left:0 and right:0 respectively.)

Comment: @PaulO'B fair point. I always forget about those since my Mac hides scrollbars by default. I think overflow hidden on the wrapper would be the best solution however

Answer (score 0):

*showing a diagram would have been good than this zigzag*

One way of doing it is to use **js** and *I guess css can do that*.

**Try this:**

```
<script>

document.getElementById("yourDivId").width = (window.innerWidth - 1140)/2

</script>
```

*N.B: dont forget to put this code after your div*

Comment: sry, forgot to mention that I am using ASP.NET

Comment: find a way to write js code in asp.net here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848359/how-to-write-javascript-in-asp-net-in-code-behind-using-c-sharp